# SQL - Join Tables and show "empty" values too

Tags: mysql

i have a question. i have one table with interface strings (interface_string_id, name), i.e. 181 - SEARCH, 183 - SEARCH_NOT and so on

and a second table with the language translation strings (language_id, interface_string_id, string), ie. cz - 181 - hledáni, 183 - cz - nehledat, de - 181 - suche, de - 183 - nicht suchen.

now i want to build a table with join where i also want to create "empty" rows for interface string, which are still missing.

is there a way how i can achieve this?

also, is that way the tables were built better or worse in performance (the structure side IMO is awful).

peace, jesta

Comment: You can use left join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN to show fields from both tables, including ones with empty or null values.

```
select
lt.language_id,
lt.interface_string_id,
lt.string,
i.name
from language_translation_string lt
left join interface_string i on i.interface_string_id = lt.interface_string_id
```